# javascript replacing multiple characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I've searched n revised JS for replacing alphabetical letters(characters) with new ones, but I also want to replace multiple characters with different ones.

i. e. words combined with 'w' letter(like gw, kw) SHOULD NOT be printed as Ñ± but ¼£. But code below isn't working properly :(

Any ideas are appreciated.

```
$(function() {
$("textarea").keyup(function() {
    var word = $(this).val();
    var tifinaghized = word.replace(/[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]|gw|kw/g, function(s) {
        return alphabet[s];
    });
    $("div").text(tifinaghized);
});
});

var alphabet = {
'a': 'Æ',
'b': 'ⴱ',
'c': 'Î',
'd': 'Ë',
'e': 'Ã',
'f': 'â',
'g': 'Ñ',
...
'w': '±',
...
'gw': '¼£', 
'kw': 'Ã¾'
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the regexp to

```
/gw|kw|[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]/g
```

Comment: +1 Or `/[abcdefhijlmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]|gw|kw|[gk]/g` But yours is better :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. The idea here is that only when multiple letter combinations(`gw`) do not match, then we go ahead to match the single letter combinations.

```
$(function() {
    $("textarea").keyup(function() {
        var word = $(this).val();
        var tifinaghized = word.replace(/gw|kw|[a-z]/gi, function(s) {
            return alphabet[s];
        });
        $("div").text(tifinaghized);
    });
});
```